# Show Image after choosing it from html form

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to show picture after choosing it from html form following this code: 
http://jsfiddle.net/LvsYc/

and my code is:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
  <!-- The above 3 meta tags *must* come first in the head; any other head content must come *after* these tags -->
  <meta name="description" content="">
  <meta name="author" content="">
  <link rel="icon" href="bootstrap/favicon.ico">

  <title>Image Test</title>
  <link href="bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <script src="bootstrap/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <link href="bootstrap/signin.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <script>
    function readURL(input) {
      if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
        var reader = new FileReader();

        reader.onload = function(e) {
          $('#blah').attr('src', e.target.result);
        }

        reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
      }
    }

    $("#imgInp").change(function() {
      readURL(this);
    });
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <form id="form12" runat="server">
      <input type='file' id="imgInp" />
      <img id="blah" src="#" alt="your image" />
    </form>

    <script src="../../assets/js/ie10-viewport-bug-workaround.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

But the chosen image is not shown. What am I doing wrong? It looks almost like the example above.

Comment: It's working fine for me, I don't see an issue

Comment: Are you getting any javascript errors in the browser dev tools console?

Comment: @Ageonix,  No, I`m not.

Comment: Strange, it's working for me as well.  Maybe an issue with the image your uploading?  Did you try multiple images?

Comment: Yes, I tried it with multiple images with the same effect. And it is doing the same issue also on server and also on localhost.